# How to fix the text area box in Unity inspector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I recently updated unity from the 2018.3.2f1 version to the 2019.3.0a5 version. I decided to open up one of my games in the new version of unity. Everything seemed to be working as normal, but then I noticed that my the text area of my box had shrunk to the one line even though my code still showed that I had changed that with TextArea. This is something I need to fix fast because I'm working on a text game. Is there anyway to fix this or even to change my game to the old unity version?

I tried changing the size that I had TextArea on and changing the command to "Multiline" but it didn't do anything.

```
[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "State")]
public class State : ScriptableObject
{
    [TextArea(14,10)] [SerializeField] string storyText;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`2019.3.0a5` is an `Alpha` version (therefore the `a`).

It seems that they are introducing a completely new/different GUI layout and the `[TextArea]` attribute doesn't work currently.

There are two known issues related to that especialy the first one:

- UI: Text input field does not resize in the inspector. ([1156028](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/ui-text-input-field-does-not-resize-in-the-inspector))

but maybe also this one

- Editor - Other: CustomPropertyDrawers have different behavior now in 2019.2 ([1156837](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/custompropertydrawers-have-different-behavior-now-in-2019-dot-2))

read more at [What's new in Unity 2019.3.0 Alpha 5](https://unity3d.com/de/unity/alpha/2019.3.0a5)

---

**In general:** Avoid doing huge jumps in Unity versions .. especially jumping to **alpha** or **beta** versions ... as the name says they are basically **for testing only**

**Safety first** - try to upgrade incrementally, make tests and stop on the latest stable version like currently `2019.1.7`! except you reaaally need a feature from the alpha and beta versions

**Always** make backups before migrating a project to a newer version. Start using VersionControl like e.g. [`Git`](https://git-scm.com/) so you can easily revert any changes made by the upgrade process.

---

Downgrading a Project to an older Unity version might work but most of the times also brings some trouble. During the upgrade Unity automatically makes some changes according to the change list of the newer version.

It sometimes doesn't work that smooth in the other direction since the older Unity version ofcourse has no information about what changes the later versions brought.

You can try and remove everything from your project folder **except**

- The `Assets` folder
- The `ProjectSettings` folder
- The `Packages` folder (but make sure you read the `Logs/Packages-Update.log`) in order to find out if there where any changes made to the packages

You can ofcourse also simply delete the `Packages` folder and then later after opnening your project in the older version re-install all the packages you need via the `PackageManager`.

all other folders and files are generated by Unity automatically so you can remove them and Unity will restore them the next time you open the project.

---

The fastest way to cleanup your project is as said to use `Git` and have a `.gitignore` file like e.g. [Github Unity .gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore) where you can also see which files can be deleted.

To set it up now install [Git](https://git-scm.com/), open the Git Bash in your project folder and run

```
git init
```

then add a new file `.gitignore` with the content from the link and run

```
git add .gitignore

git commit -m "initial ommit"
```

then run

```
git add *
```

this will throw a warning for every ignored file but you can ignore that. Again run

```
git commit -m "Added current project state"
```

and then run

```
git clean -xfd
```

which automatically deletes any file that is listed as ignored in the `.gitignore` and also any untracked file (new files that are not version controlled - wheren't added by `git add` - so far).

Again ... before doing all of that you should make a **Backup** ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go back to an earlier version, just delete the Library folder in your project, and open your project in the original version of Unity. That should work fine **as long as there were no code changes made by you or the Unity code updater**.

You may also need to edit the file `ProjectSettings/ProjectVersion.txt` with the version number you're reverting to.

You may also run into problems with the Unity Package Manager, as upgrading your project will likely also change the `Packages/manifest.json` file. If you can still open your project in the older version of Unity, you'll have to manually fix the versions of any used packages.

This is why Unity always warns you when you're opening an existing project in a newer Unity version, and why they don't support downgrading.

Comment: Unfortunately sometimes it's not that simple ;) During the upgrade process Unity recompiles and sometimes automatically changes your code in using a change list that contains every change made between previous versions and the new one. This automatic downgrading does not work ofcourse since the older version has no information about what later changes the newer version will bring. Especially now with the PackageManager this might bring some trouble

Comment: True, I forgot about the Package Manager. Added some more info. Your point about having a backup is the most important one of course.